# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: V2_1 in GData analytics

Tags: spring, maven, google-analytics, gdata

In my project I am showing analytics of some url. All thing was working fine but from some time i am not able to initialize the AnalyticsService on the local machine. I am getting following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: V2_1
at org.osaf.cosmo.ui.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:48)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RewrittenUrl.doRewrite(RewrittenUrl.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.osaf.cosmo.filters.UsernameRequestIntegrationFilter.doFilter(UsernameRequestIntegrationFilter.java:63)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.osaf.cosmo.log.HttpLoggingFilter.doFilter(HttpLoggingFilter.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:359)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
at com.stpl.pats.filters.AccountActivationCheckFilter.doFilterInternal(AccountActivationCheckFilter.java:78)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:268)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:229)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.stpl.pats.filters.WarningContextClearingFilter.doFilter(WarningContextClearingFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.osaf.cosmo.ui.VersionHeaderFilter.doFilter(VersionHeaderFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.osaf.cosmo.filters.HttpOverrideFilter.doFilter(HttpOverrideFilter.java:67)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.stpl.pats.commons.visitorcontext.filter.HttpSessionVisitorContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionVisitorContextIntegrationFilter.java:127)
at com.stpl.pats.commons.visitorcontext.filter.HttpSessionVisitorContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionVisitorContextIntegrationFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.stpl.pats.commons.metadata.filter.MetaDataIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(MetaDataIntegrationFilter.java:127)
at com.stpl.pats.commons.metadata.filter.MetaDataIntegrationFilter.doFilter(MetaDataIntegrationFilter.java:58)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.stpl.pats.filters.HttpSessionEComContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionEComContextIntegrationFilter.java:163)
at com.stpl.pats.filters.HttpSessionEComContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionEComContextIntegrationFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:138)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: V2_1
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:523)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:453)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.osaf.cosmo.ui.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:44)

Please help me as I am not able to complete my project due to this problem. The POM entries for GData Analytics are as follows

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google</groupId>
<artifactId>gdata-base</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>gdata-analytics</groupId>
  <artifactId>gdata-analytics</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
 <groupId>gdata-analytics-meta</groupId>
 <artifactId>gdata-analytics-meta</artifactId>
 <version>2.1</version>
 <type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
<groupId>com.google</groupId>
<artifactId>gdata-core</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>com.google</groupId>
<artifactId>gdata-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
<groupId>gdata-client-meta</groupId>
<artifactId>gdata-client-meta</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
<groupId>com.google</groupId>
<artifactId>gdata-calendar</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
<groupId>com.google</groupId>
<artifactId>gdata-contacts</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
<groupId>com.google</groupId>
<artifactId>gdata-media</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
<groupId>com.google</groupId>
<artifactId>gdata-photos</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<type>jar</type>
<scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with this too and it took a while to track down, but the problem is most likely with your gdata-core-1.0.jar.

It turns out that all gdata-core-1.0.jars are not the same (regardless of the 1.0 version number).  Go to http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list and download the latest zip file (currently:gdata-src.java-1.45.0.zip).  Decompress in the zip and in the ./java/lib/ you will find the latest version of the gdata-core-1.0.jar library.  Try using this one and you may want replace any other older libs while you are at it.

Good Luck